# Applying Alternating Series Error(I think): Is there a typo in this question?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find the number of terms required to determine the sum of the series with error less than .0001

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\bbox[yellow]2}{n^2 + 1}$$

This problem appears in the section where I applied Alt. Series test on everything and I can assume that there is a typo in that the exponent of the numerator should be $n$ or $n+1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely there is a typo as it makes no sense to write $(-1)^2$.

If you know the correction is either $n$ or $n+1$, either should give you the same answer since they only differ by a sign.
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^2 + 1}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n}}{n^2 + 1}$$

Comment: Is the answer 99 terms because the 100th term is less than .0001?

Comment: $99$ terms sufficies. [python](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_H7t9mcaMoNDJpd5.py) code shows that the minimal required terms are fewer than that actually.